# PHP string cookie define

Tags: php, string, cookies, constants

I have a string defined like:

```
DEFINE('IMAGES_DIR',"/portal/images/");
```

After I place it inside of a cookie its content becomes

```
%2Fportal%2Fimages%2F
```

I need the string to return like:

```
/portal/images/
```

Comment: use `setrawcookie` or urldecode it later

Answer (score 1):

I'm kinda combining two answers mentioned here.

## 1st

what you described is the default behaviour, PHP will automatically decode it to its original value, you don't need to do `urldecode($_COOKIE['name']);`

## 2nd

You can prevent automatic url encoding by using [setrawcookie()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setrawcookie.php)

## [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php)

> Note that the value portion of the cookie will automatically be urlencoded when you send the cookie, and when it is received, it is automatically decoded and assigned to a variable by the same name as the cookie name. If you don't want this, you can use setrawcookie() instead if you are using PHP 5.

Comment: Your "1st" answer is inconsistent with the very docs you quoted: *"when it is received, it is automatically decoded"*

Answer (score 0):

Use `urldecode` when getting cookie value:

```
echo urldecode('%2Fportal%2Fimages%2F');
```

or

```
//for cookie
echo urldecode($_COOKIE['IMAGES_DIR']);

//for your example above with the contant
echo urldecode(IMAGES_DIR);
```

Comment: Thank you! the urldecode set me on the right path, i am using javascript to parse the cookie contents :) thank you! ecodeURIComponent()

Comment: You shouldn't need to decode it. OP must be fetching the cookie by means other than `$_COOKIE`.